# Installing custom recovery using Odin will erase data or not?

Tags: twrp, odin

My phone's model is sm-g5108q(SAMSUNG G5108Q Galaxy Core Max).

I'm going to install custom recovery on my phone.
But I can't found custom recovery package suitable my phone.
So I prepare custom recovery package similar version.

1. Installing custom recovery will erase data?
2. Is there any problem others?

Comment: It will not wipe data; however, using an image for another device is always a dangerous (if it flashes at all) idea.

Answer (score 0):

The installation itself will not erase any user data, but to boot a custom system image or custom recovery, your bootloader needs to be unlocked. If it isn't already, then unlocking the bootloader **will** erase all user data.

Note also that it is generally not possible to use a system image or recovery that was prepared for a different phone. Samsung in particular tends to release two completely different phone models under the same marketing name. Commonly one has an SM- model number like yours, and the other has a GT- model number. ROMs made for one model will not work at all on the other model.